# how to unit test a basic ternary using karma-mocha/chai-enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai, enzyme, karma-mocha

At work we are using Karma-Mocha with Chai-Enzyme to unit test our react code. I'm hoping some one could give me a basic example on how to unit test a basic ternary.

Example ternary such as this:

```
{myVariable === null ? 'DefaultString' : myVariable}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more of your component.

Comment: First, I believe you may have the check backwards. Second, it would need to be 2 or more tests. One for the null condition, and one for not null.

Comment: You're correct @ovation22, I had the logic backwards in the ternary example. Fixed that...it's not one I'm actually using..just an example. Abstracted it a bit so folks don't fixate on the this.props. It's just a ternary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the ternary expression is part of some JSX element.

So you can use Enzyme's **[text](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/text.html)** method in order to extract the text of the element.

```js
import mount from 'enzyme';

describe('example text', () => {
  it('should show', () => {
    const wrapper = mount( <MyComp> );
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.be('DefaultString');
  });
});
```

Comment: Just add to do 2 it's. to cover both scenario's.